# Can I daisy chain multiple displayPort monitors from a single thunderbolt port on an XPS 15 laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, dell-xps, thunderbolt, daisychaining

I currently use DP chaining to connect two Dell U2414h displays to the mDP port on my 9343 XPS 13.

I'm looking at upgrading to a newer XPS 15, which has 1 x HDMI, 2 x USB3 and 1 x thunderbolt port.

I just want to clarify that I can run both external displays off of a single port - the thunderbolt, I assume?

Furthermore, if I was to buy a 3rd external screen, could I add that to the chain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it works !

You can do a Thunderbolt to DP connection on your first monitor and then DP to DP between your monitors.

However beware of the limitations when it comes to how many monitors can be linked based on resolution: 
4 Full HD
2 QHD
1 4K

As for the 3rd monitor added to the daisychain, to be honest i never tried that but hey ... you still have a HDMI port still available but that will mess up you "cable typology " if you go for a "minimal cable desk solution"